# Custom node package does not provide an export named

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, node-modules

I feel like I've tried everything but nothing seem to work.

I have created and published the following module:

**Index.ts :**

```
import ContentIOService from "./IOServices/ContentIOService";

export = {
    ContentIOService: ContentIOService,
}
```

Where `ContentIOService` is the following file:

```
import {SuperIO} from "../Framework/SuperIO";
export interface ICMSContentData {
    id: number;
    url: string;
    htmlTag: string;
    importJSComponent: string;
    componentData: string
}

export interface CMSData {
    id: number;
    url: string;
    htmlTag: string;
    importJSComponent: string;
    componentData: Object
}

export default  class ContentIOService extends SuperIO {

    private static instance: ContentIOService;

    public static getInstance(): ContentIOService {
        if (!ContentIOService.instance) {
            ContentIOService.instance = new ContentIOService();
        }
        return ContentIOService.instance;
    }

    public async GetContent(url: string) {
        const response = await super.get<ICMSContentData[]>(url, {});
        try {
            if (response?.parsedBody) {
                return this.ProcessResponse(response.parsedBody);
            } else {
                this.handleHTTPError(new Error("Error"))
            }

        } catch (e) {
            this.handleHTTPError(e);
        }

    }

    private ProcessResponse(ContentData: ICMSContentData[]): CMSData[] {
        let CMSData: CMSData[] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < ContentData.length; i++) {
            CMSData.push({
                id: ContentData[i].id,
                url: ContentData[i].url,
                htmlTag: ContentData[i].htmlTag,
                importJSComponent: ContentData[i].importJSComponent,
                componentData: this.parseComponentData(ContentData[i].componentData)
            })
        }
        return CMSData;
    }

    private handleHTTPError(e: Error) {
        console.log(e)
    }


    private parseComponentData(parseAbleString: string): Object {
        return JSON.parse(parseAbleString);
    }
}
```

Then I have built this together and bundled it into a `/lib` folder:

[image]

This is built with the following `tsconfig`

```
  {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

For the sake of argument I will also post my `Package.json` should that be necessary:

```
    {
  "name": "sdk-io-package",
  "version": "1.1.6",
  "description": "",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --config jestconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Marc Rasmussen",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "25.2.2",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jest": "25.2.2",
    "prettier": "^2.1.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.3.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I publish this module on my private proget server and import it in my other project:

[image]

Where the index.js file looks like this:

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
var ContentIOService_1 = __importDefault(require("./IOServices/ContentIOService"));
module.exports = {
    ContentIOService: ContentIOService_1.default,
};
```

Then inside of my typescript I import it:

```
import {LitElement, html, customElement, property} from 'lit-element';
import {ContentIOService} from 'sdk-io-package';
@customElement('my-test-element')
export class MyTestElement extends LitElement {

    @property()
    text: string = "Hello world";

    render() {
        this.test();
        return html`
        ${this.text} 
    `;
    }

  async  test (){
        const instance = ContentIOService.getInstance();
        const data = instance.GetContent("https://httpbin.org/get")
        console.log(data);
    }
}

declare global {
    interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
        'my-test-element': MyTestElement;
    }
}
```

I then run my application (it builds without any typescript errors) and serve, Go to the browser and I get the following error:

[image]

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: The requested module '../../node_modules/sdk-io-package/lib/index.js' does not provide an export named 'ContentIOService'

I simply don't know what I've done wrong.

**Small update**

When I look in the browser in the node_modules folder I actually don't see the folders inside lib and thereby not the module?:

[image]

Comment: `export = { ContentIOService: ContentIOService, }` looks very much like a syntax error in javascript.

Comment: Oh wait, the question is using typescript…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
export = {
    ContentIOService: ContentIOService,
}
```

This does NOT export a value named `ContentIOService`. Instead, it's a default export of an object that has a property named `ContentIOService`. Those two scenarios are not the same thing.

A named export would look more like this:

```
import _ContentIOService from "./IOServices/ContentIOService";

export const ContentIOService = _ContentIOService;
```

Which you can clean up by using a [re-export](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#re-exports):

```
export { default as ContentIOService } from "./IOServices/ContentIOService";
```

Comment: The second form is beautiful. First isn't right. Without the reexport default syntax, it would have been `export {default as ContentIOService} from "./IOServices/ContentIOService";`, or `import ContentIOService from "./IOServices/ContentIOService"; export {ContentIOService}`. Unfortunately, well it looks like it would work adding the intermediate const breaks TS if it's a class and module semantics at any rate

Comment: Sorry when I said second I meant your second version was good not the second code snippet. So `export ContentIOService from "./IOServices/ContentIOService"` as you had before is the best option today. But the one with an intermediate `const` is off. And should be intermediate const is should just be `
import ContentIOService from "./IOServices/ContentIOService"; export {ContentIOService};`. `export { default as ContentIOService } from "./IOServices/ContentIOService"` is also good

Comment: Anyway, I'm going to vote for this in anticipation and get some rest, been up for like 2 days straight.